# Como passar um {{$index}} do ng-repeat como parâmetro num mixin? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat, jade

Estou trabalhando com aquivos .jade e usando ng-repeat do angularjs 1.5.8.
Não consigo passar um {{$index}} como parâmetro num mixin.
Esse parâmetro é uma string que define um ng-model dentro do mixin.

Ex.:

```
.row(ng-repeat="atendimento in cadastro.atendimento")
     +checkbox("cadastro.perfil[{{$index}}].nome", true, null)
```

o Erro ocorre nas chaves "{{ }}" e parece ter relação por estar dentro dos colchetes '[ ]'. Se enviar apenas "{{$index}}", funciona normalmente, assim como o esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Então, você está alocando ele de forma errada.

Vamos lá.

No ng-repeat utilize desta forma:

```
td(ng-repeat='atendimento in cadastro.atendimento track by $index')
    +checkbox("{{cadastro.perfil[$index].nome}}", indice="{{$index}}")
```

uma forma também:

```
ng-model="cadastro.perfil[$index]"
```

Comment: Olá, Rebeca. Acabou que esqueci de comentar sua resposta. Na época, sua ajuda foi fundamental. Obrigado.